# sp_OACreate vbscript.regexp Class not registered

Tags: sql-server-2005, regular-expression

Imagine a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition.

I can create a 'vbscript.regexp' object using a vbscript (confirming that the DLL is registered).

I cannot create a 'vbscript.regexp' object using sp_OACreate in a SQL Server 2005 SP3 (.4053)(cluster) environment.

OLE Automation is checked ON in surface area configuration.

The sp_OACreate was working until very recently.

Can you help me?

****CODE****

```
            declare
                @source varchar(5000),
                @regexp varchar(1000),
                @replace varchar(1000),
                @globalReplace bit,
                @ignoreCase bit

            set @source = 'NBG76TF43'
            set @regexp = '[^0-9]'
            set @replace = ''
            set @globalReplace = 1
            set @ignoreCase = 1

                DECLARE @hr integer
                DECLARE @objRegExp integer
                DECLARE @result varchar(5000)

                EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'VBScript.RegExp', @objRegExp OUTPUT
                IF @hr <> 0 
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @objRegExp
                        PRINT  'A'
                        PRINT @hr
                    END
                EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @objRegExp, 'Pattern', @regexp
                IF @hr <> 0 
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @objRegExp
                        PRINT  'B'
                        PRINT @hr
                    END
                EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @objRegExp, 'Global', @globalReplace
                IF @hr <> 0 
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @objRegExp
                        PRINT  'C'
                        PRINT @hr
                    END
                EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @objRegExp, 'IgnoreCase', @ignoreCase
                IF @hr <> 0 
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @objRegExp
                        PRINT  'D'
                        PRINT @hr
                    END

                EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @objRegExp, 'Replace', @result OUTPUT, @source, @replace
                IF @hr <> 0 
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @objRegExp
                        PRINT  'E'
                        PRINT @hr
                    END

                EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @objRegExp
                    IF @hr <> 0 
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT  'F'
                        PRINT @hr
                        END

                PRINT  @result

            /*
            A
            -2147211480
            B
            -2147211480
            C
            -2147211480
            D
            -2147211480
            E
            -2147211480
            F
            -2147211480
            */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten months later, the issue occurred again on the same system.

- Specific error: 0x8007045A (A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed)

I cannot find the cause of this issue. However, I found enough related scenarios  (ten months ago) that suggested that rebooting the server would solve the problem.

I rebooted the server cluster (both nodes, following controlled failovers), and the issue was resolved (can create a 'vbscript.regexp' object using sp_OACreate).

Comment: Why don't you just use CLR regular expressions instead of these antiquated automation procedures?